# Display ViewPart in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, dot, zest

I am currently developing an eclipse plugin which displays DOT-Graphs. For this purpose I make use of [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest#Graphviz_DOT_support) plugin. However, I have no idea how to actually display the graph which I built. I want to display it in the middle of the eclipse window as an Editor.

To get this done I created a custom Editor class which needs some code in its createPartControl(Composite) code in order to make use of the DotGraphView which is provided by the plugin.

The question is, how can I display this DotGraphView? 

The code of my Editor looks like this:

```java
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite container) {
    DotImport importer = new DotImport(TEST_GRAPH);
    Graph graph = importer.newGraphInstance();
    DotGraphView dotGraphView = new DotGraphView();
    dotGraphView.setGraph(graph);

    // add dotGraphView as a child to container and display it
    // What todo here?
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have problems as DotGraphView is designed to be located in an `IViewSite`. It makes some calls to `getViewSite()` which would be an issue if you're embedding it in an editor. You could possibly provide your own `IViewSite` implementation to pass to it's `init()` method and delegate most calls to your `IEditorSite`, but don't know if you'd run into any further problems.

Comment: How can I realise this using a normal View? Post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To use the graph in your own custom view, check out the implementation of [`ZestFxUiView`](https://github.com/eclipse/gef4/blob/master/org.eclipse.gef4.zest.fx.ui/src/org/eclipse/gef4/zest/fx/ui/view/ZestFxUiView.java), the superclass of [`DotGraphView`](https://github.com/eclipse/gef4/blob/master/org.eclipse.gef4.dot.ui/src/org/eclipse/gef4/internal/dot/ui/DotGraphView.java). You could probably subclass `ZestFxUiView` and call `setGraph` with your graph object.